# Records not getting passed from Apex to LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass the Order record from Apex to LWC and make and perform some
operations on JS controller side.
One of my main requirements is to bring in all the Order Item associated
to the order to the JS.
I am able to pass the orderItems if they are less than 125. If I have items 125 or
greater, I only get 62 child records in the array.

Below is my Apex code which I have written based on my requirments. The
instance 'pr' stores the given order record along with the child
records.

```
@AuraEnabled()
public static E_Order__c getOrderDetails(Id recordId){
    try {
        Map<String,String> orderFields = Send2SAPHelper.getOrderFields('Order');
        String query_string = 'Select '+orderFields.get('parentFields')+',(Select '+orderFields.get('childFields')+' From E_OrderItems__r) FROM E_Order__c WHERE Id=\''+recordId+'\'';
        E_Order__c pr = Database.query(query_string);
        System.debug(pr.E_OrderItems__r.size()); //Size is 250 in debug console
        return pr;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The helper class just helps me retrieve all the custom fields from Custom meta data in string. Helper code:

```
@AuraEnabled()
public static Map<String,String> getOrderFields(String label){
    try{
    SendToSAP__mdt fields = [select Field_API_Name__c,Child_Fields__c from SendToSAP__mdt where MasterLabel=: label];
    Map<String,String> orderFields = new Map<String,String>();
    orderFields.put('parentFields',fields.Field_API_Name__c);
    orderFields.put('childFields', fields.Child_Fields__c);
    return orderFields;
}catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I print the child records in apex, I get the size as 250 and send this to the controller.

On the JS side I have defined a function:

```
getOrderDetails( { recordId: this.recordId})
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('The length is....');
        console.log(data.E_OrderItems__r.length); //Length is 62 in browser console
    })
    .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
    });
```

On the browser console, I get the length as 62 which are the first 62 order items in my array list.

I tried to return JSON.serialize(pr) from Apex also but that also gave the same results.
I tried to convert the object instance to String.valueof(pr) but that only displayed
the parent fields in my LWC. Child records were missing in the string.

On experimenting with different combinations, I found out that if order items
are 125 or more, it will only return 62 items. 124 items works perfectly. This
has something to do with Salesforce optimization between Lightning and apex but I am not sure why.

I have been struggling to get a work around this and would really appreciate
if someone could help me with this particular issue.

Comment: Did you check the debug logs for the aura enabled method when called from the component?

Comment: Very strange... just one thing - maybe change the `@AuraEnabled()` to `@AuraEnabled`... just in case apex is expecting a param of some sort. Also, have you tried `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)`